# Is it possible to have one file for multiple translations?

Tags: inkscape

I have a document that contains text in English, but I also want to translate it to Spanish without having two separate copies. I say so because if I update the design on the English one, I would like the Spanish one to update automatically. If not, I need to apply every change I make to all the different translations.

Comment: In Inkscape there's no such functionality at present.  Currently, Inkscape doesn't support multi-page documents or master pages.  Perhaps have a look at Scribus or other similar page layout software instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a suggestion:

I'd use a single document, with separate layers for text in different languages.

So you have only one drawing, and when you export your drawing, you make visible only one of the text layers at a time.

Comment: There are also scripts like https://github.com/janoliver/inkslides to export the different versions automatically.